# Mobile viewport stopped working

Tags: html, mobile, viewport

I have a blog website where I used the `viewport` property to scale the site in mobiles, it was working perfectly using:

```
<meta name="viewport" />
```

Then it stopped working for no reason, didn't touch the code at all. Now I've been trying with everything I find online, from max-width to initial-scale, etc. Still doesn't work.

What could be happening? Is there any update that cancelled the `viewport` property?

My website: [www.fake-leather.com](http://www.fake-leather.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not coding a responsive site, just don’t use any meta viewport. If you are coding a responsive website, all you need to write is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Any additional parameters in the content attribute usually screw up user’s experience.

Reference: [Stop using the viewport meta tag (until you know how to use it)](http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho)

Comment: I tried with and without the meta tag, still not working. It's so weird that this worked for a few months without any problem and one good morning decided to stop working?